# WebDriver: Chrome custom profile doesn't work?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

WebDriver: Chrome custom profile doesn't work?

- I have setup a new profile (Many profiles) and have attempted to point to one of the profiles with the code below however when the browser open there is no indication that the new profile is being used?

  ```
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Base_Page.getConstant(Constant.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY));
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/gianni.bruno/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 1/Default");
          options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("test-type");
          options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
          options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
          webdriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  ```

Shouldn't i see something like the following?

[image]